# Is there an English word for the Spanish pepper called Ñora?

Tags: language, chili-peppers, spanish-cuisine

**Is there an English word for the Spanish pepper called Ñora?**

I have translated the following from [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91ora)

> The ñora is a cultivated variety of Capsicum annuum or pepper, called
> "bola" in Alicante and Murcia, where it became popular. It is small in
> size, round in shape and red in color when ripe, and is then left to
> dry in the sun. It has a sweet flavor and is widely used in the
> gastronomy of the Spanish Levante, especially in the Region of Murcia,
> the Valencian Community (Alicante) and in Catalonia.

[image][image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly not. They look and sound a lot like cherry peppers, aka pimiento peppers, but are apparently a distinct cultivar. With the exception of commercially important (“Maris Piper”) or widely renowned (“Honeycrisp”) names, cultivars tend to be quite local in penetration, and are unlikely to have translations in other languages.

You’d probably do fine to substitute cherry peppers, if you’re trying to make a particular recipe which calls for them.

Comment: Agreed in that we typically just use the original name for varieties of peppers.  (Jalapeño, habanero, chipotle, ancho, poblano, serrano, arbol, etc.)  But I don't know that I'd say "substitute cherry peppers" without knowing anything other than the shape of it.  And the description in the question says "is then left to dry in the sun", so it might be a dried pepper.  (as there are many cases like jalapeño/chipotle, poblano/ancho, anaheim/colorado, in which the name is not just the specific variety of pepper but if it's dried or not (and how it's dried)).

Answer (score 0):

From [ProZ.com](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/spanish-to-english/cooking-culinary/3001270-%C3%B1ora.html):

> **Spanish term or phrase: ñora**
>
> **English translation:    Nora (dried) pepper/chilie**

ProZ.com is a translation community, where anyone can ask translation questions. You can ask your own question here: https://www.proz.com/ask/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure why it has been down-voted. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: because it just says "dried pepper" which would also apply to say an ancho, a habanero, etc. (I didn't downvote but it seems really obvious - saying a random dictionary site translates ñora to Nora is not helpful.

Comment: @KateGregory It's not a dictionary, it's a community, where people can ask questions, and other people answer them.

Comment: (information that might have been useful in the answer, no?) and anyway the answer remains "this one location out of the whole internet doesn't have a translation for it other than changing the character set a bit" which is not helping anyone.

Comment: @KateGregory : but mexican names for peppers are often different for dried vs. non-dried.  So it's quite possible that all ñora peppers are dried, with a different name for when it's fresh.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica One issue here is that the citations on that translation are all websites selling the peppers, and it's *extremely* common for English sites to drop diacritical marks from non-English words, so it's not really clear whether "nora" is actually a translation of ñora, or just a careless transliteration. I've seen "jalapeno" more times than I can count, and I wouldn't say it's a translation of jalapeño.